# По какому параметру Steam отслеживает компьютеры пользователя?

Tags: windows, steam

В **Steam** каждому аккаунту соответствует множество уникальных домашних компьютеров, с которых может быть получен доступ к этому аккаунту. Как **Steam** определяет, на какой именно пользовательский компьютер он был установлен, иначе говоря, как он его идентифицирует?

Comment: к железу привязывается скорее всего. У железа ПК есть свои идентификаторы, которые не повторяются. Ещё может быть ставят свои метки в реестр или ещё куда-то.

Comment: Речь о сохранении пароля?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Можно привязать аккаунт к MAC-адресу + меткам, оставленным самим приложением в реестре (на тот случай, если на машине стоит несколько ОС и аккаунт необходимо идентифицировать для каждой). Всем спасибо за комментарии.